# Docker mounting different path with same config on 2 different machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My docker compose entry for the service is:

```
  api:
    restart: always
    build: ./project/api
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app:ro
      - ~/data:/root/data:ro  # /root is the ~ in container
```

I run my containers using

```
sudo docker-compose down && sudo docker-compose up --build -d
```

I have 2 different machines, both with `admin` user. On inspection of the containers created:

```
sudo docker inspect project_api_1 | grep Mounts -A20
```

On machine 1, admin user is `admin:x:1005:1001:Admin User,,,:/home/admin:/bin/zsh` and `admin:x:1000:1000:Debian:/home/admin:/bin/zsh` on machine 2

Output on machine 1

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/admin/project",
            "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/admin/data",
            "Destination": "/root/data",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

Output on machine 2

```
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/admin/project",
            "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        },
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/root/data",
            "Destination": "/root/data",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

On machine 1, `/root/data` points to `/home/admin/data` which is the desired behavior, but on machine 2 it points to `/root/data`. I can fix this by using either relative path `./data` (which symlinks to ~/data) or by using absolute path `/home/admin/data`. My docker version is same on both machines - `Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87`

I'm curious about why is this different?

Comment: What is the command you are using? And in what user are you running the commands  on each machine?

Comment: @yamenK Updated the question with the commands. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

On your yaml file, you're using **~/data**, where ~ is the shorthand for the home directory of the user you used to run docker. From that, I guess you're running docker on machine 1 as admin, while you're running docker on machine 2 as root.

You should remember that the source directory is a directory on your host machine (not the container), so the user relevant to **~** is the user on your host machine.

Comment: I'm the same user on both machines: admin. See the other mount in the inspect logs.

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary Can you provide the uid for the admin user on both machines?

Comment: @yamenK `admin:x:1005:1001:Admin User,,,:/home/admin:/bin/zsh` on machine 1 and `admin:x:1000:1000:Debian:/home/admin:/bin/zsh` on machine 2